# Why do some .js files appear plain text files on vscode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Like in the image below, while most .js files turn out to be javascript files, some in the same project choose to be text files although they still have .js on the file name. The content is also in correct javascript syntax and I can't tell what went wrong.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI74f.png]

Comment: What directory are they in?

Comment: Have you tried restarting VSCode? What does _"incorrect javascript syntax"_ mean? Can you give an example of some of the file content?

Comment: Sorry I meant "in correct syntax". And they are in pcm/templates/... other files in pcm/... don't have any issues and it's only the files in this folder

Comment: can you check your user and workspace vscode settings files to see if any of them have a `"files.associations"` entry that is affecting this? The setting can map glob patterns to file types to be used for files matching the glob pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The most common explanation is they are .txt files. In other words, it means that the file's full name is something like `index.js.txt`.

Can you check the file type? You can quickly do that by:

1. Right-click on the file name;
2. Select the option "copy path";
3. Past it in some .txt file. Check if you obtain something like this: `C:\{some-path}\index.js.txt`

If you still see `index.js` check the file type. Sometimes when new files are created, the operating system does not create that file with the extension type that we define in the file name.

The solution is just to create another file, ensure that the operating system detects the file type, copy the content to this new file, and delete the old one.

Comment: Does vscode hide extensions?

Comment: Thanks but there are no .txt when I do that. I only see ~/index.js

Comment: @jj993 I updated the answer. If you still are still seeing index.js check the file type. Sometimes when new files are created, the operating system does not create that file with the extension type that we define in the file name. The solution is just to create another file making sure that the operation system detects the file, copy the content to this new file and delete the old one.

Comment: I just tried that but once any file is copied or created inside this folder, it turns into a text file